# Google oauth authorization code expired?

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-api-php-client

After finally getting something besides NULL to be returned for an access token or refresh token, I am now getting an error saying my authorization token is expired. I've tried authorizing with 2 different Google accounts at different hours of the day, but I keep on getting the same authorization token.

How do I get a new, valid authorization token? When I go to account settings to remove authorization access for the app I am building in hopes to reset it, it isn't listed as an authorized app / service.

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$redirect_uri = 'site url';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
var_dump($refreshToken);
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
$aT = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
var_dump($accessToken);
var_dump($aT);
```

The last line is what returns the error. The other `var_dump`s return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The process you are following for authentication is not the proper one, or at least that what it seems. After setting the client configuration you have to check if you have an access code, if there is no access code then you redirect the user to authenticate and after the user is authenticated, you redirect the user to do what you want. You are also missing the scopes your app needs in order to get proper access. Delete your app from the [connected apps and sites](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) in your Google profile and then try the following please:

```
<?php session_start(); 

//INCLUDE PHP CLIENT LIBRARY
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$scopes = array("email");

// Create client object
$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("client_secrets.json");
$client->addScope($scopes);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');  

if ( isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION["access_token"]){


  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  print_r($_SESSION['access_token']);

  echo "<br>***************************************************************************************************************************************<br>";

  print "Access token creation time: ".date('M d, Y - H:i:s', $_SESSION['access_token']['created']);

  echo "<br>*********************************************************************<br>";

  print "Refresh token: ".$_SESSION['access_token']['refresh_token'];


} else {

    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

      $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    } else {

      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    }

}

?>
```

Please don't forget to review the documentation that explains the authorization process wich is found **[here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app).**

Comment: I'm running your exact code and have no connected apps or sites to this account and am getting NULL for the access_token and refresh_token.

Comment: in that case, it seems your client_secrets.json file is not good. Have you configured the project with the redirect URI's appropriately?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it straight from the api console. If the redirects were not configured, it would be giving me that error.

Comment: Well, I give up. Please try creating another project and creating new credentials. Sorry I couldn't help.